# Is it possible with pdfpages package to put a pdf document on a certain area of the page?

Tags: pdfpages

I have a two column document and wish to put a excerpt of a page from a pdf document in one column. Is it possible with `pdfpages`?

My code:

```
\documentclass[paper = a4, paper = landscape, pagesize, twocolumn]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin = 5mm, bottom = 25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}

  \begin{description}
    \item[Reaktionskraefte werden wie folgt bestimmt]\mbox{}
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item\textsc{Lagrange}-Funktion aufstellen.
      \item Zwangsbedingungen aufstellen.
      \item Bewegungsgleichungen aufstellen.
      \includepdf[pages = 9, noautoscale, trim = 106mm 19mm 20mm 107mm, clip]{EM_VL_skript_1314}
    \end{enumerate}
    \item[Fuer die potentielle Energie]gilt allgemein $U = mgh$, mit Masse $m$, Erdbeschleunigung $g$ und Hoehe $h$ ueber dem Nullniveau.
  \end{description}

\end{document}
```

The result, page one:[image: result_Seite_1]
And page two:[image: result_Seite_2]
The result I wish:[image: wished_result]
The [pdf document](https://www.reibungsphysik.tu-berlin.de/fileadmin/fg204/Lehre/2013_14_WiSe/EM/VL/EM_VL_skript_1314.pdf).

Thank you for your effort in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of including the page using [`pdfpages`](//ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages)'s `\includepdf`, use the regular `\includegraphics` with the `page` key-value:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}
  \item[First description item] \mbox{}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item First enumerate item
    \item Second enumerate item
    \item Third enumerate item

      \includegraphics[page = 2, width=\linewidth]{lipsum50}
  \end{enumerate}

  \newpage

  \item[Second description item]
    Some more text.
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

Note that [`graphicx`](//ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) doesn't provide the `noautoscale` option. However, it supports `trim`, `clip` (and others).

Comment: Hello @Werner! That's an easy one! Thank you!